# How to call a method from a nested class, Java?

Tags: java, nested-class

How to call methodTwo(); from methodOne(); ?

```
class Name {
    void methodOne() {
        class InnerClass {
           void methodTwo() {
           }
         }
     }
 }
```

Thank You!

Comment: You can `new InnerClass().methodTwo()`

Comment: FYI : Method local inner classes will not be available out of method where those are implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `InnerClass`, in the same way as any other instance method needs an instance on which to call it:

```
class Name {
   void methodOne() {
     class InnerClass {
       void methodTwo() {
       }
     }

     InnerClass x = new InnerClass();
     x.methodTwo();
   }
}
```

It's worth being careful before doing this - I don't think I've *ever* seen a named class declared within a method in the production code I've been associated with. Normally I'd either use an anonymous inner class for something really short, or a private static named class for anything longer, to avoid making the method too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Name {
    void methodOne() {
        class InnerClass {
           void methodTwo() {
               new InnerClass().methodTwo();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of recursive.. never ending.. result in OutOfMemory.

Answer (score -2):

Non-static nested classes are tied with containing class, but it can be many instances of nested class with one containing instance. So you need to specify instance name against which you want to run a method.